# Find <td> with class exactly equal to variable

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to filter to find a  with a particular class. At the moment I've got this

```
var element = $('td').filter(':contains('+some_variable+')');
```

The class is a number, anywhere from 1-30. So the problem I have is that when it equals 1 it filters to give the following: 1, 10, 11, 12, 13... and so on.

How can I search for an exact class contents?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.filter(fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) for exact match

```js
var element = $('td').filter(function() {
  return Number(this.textContent) === some_variable;
});
```